# mysql - group by column but show all the rows

Tags: mysql

I need help with this query, this is my output:

```
idProduccion | hp   | totalHp |
      4      | 40   | 40      |
      4      | 35   | 35      |  
      5      | 90   | 90      |
      6      | 2500 | 2500    |
```

how do I do to sum hp columns with the same idProduccion and show all the rows, for exampe:

```
idProduccion | hp   | totalHp |
      4      | 40   | 75      |
      4      | 35   | 75      |  
      5      | 90   | 90      |
      6      | 2500 | 2500    |
....
```

here is my sql query

```
SELECT 
    lp.idProduccion,lp.hp, totalHp
FROM
    lotesproduccion lp
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        lp.hp, lp.idlotesproduccion, sum(lp.hp) AS totalHp
    FROM
        lotesproduccion lp
    GROUP BY lp.idlotesproduccion) AS lp1 ON lp.idlotesproduccion = lp1.idlotesproduccion
```

Comment: why don't you post the result you are getting?

Comment: The first table is my result.. in totalHp it should go the sum of the hp with equal idProduccion, but I need to group by idProduccion and not by idlotesproduccion

Comment: You have known you need to group by `idProduccion`, then group by it in sub query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed ur query with group by idproduction

SELECT 
    lp.idProduccion,lp.hp, lp1.totalHp
FROM
    lotesproduccion lp
       Left JOIN
    (SELECT 
     lp.idProduccion , sum(lp.hp) AS totalHp
    FROM
        lotesproduccion lp
    GROUP BY lp.idProduccion) AS lp1 ON lp.idProduccion = lp1.idProduccion

Comment: It has an error code: 1054. Unknown column 'totalHp' in 'field list'

Comment: Now I have edited it ... totalhp was the alias name that you have used. I have taken that one as column name but actual column name is hp. Anyway changed it now

Comment: I modified that and erase one of the JOIN after lotesproduccion lp, but the result is the same of the first top table, it doesn´t sum the column totalhp when the idProduccion are equal..

Comment: Added onemore solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ramesh Yelda, it works really fine.. Actually the full query is this..

```
SELECT 
    il.IdLoteNuevo AS id_lotes,
    icu.idCultivosNuevo AS id_cultivos,
    YEAR(p.fechaInicio) * 10000 + MONTH(p.fechaInicio) * 100 + DAY(p.fechaInicio) AS id_fechaInicio,
    YEAR(p.fechaCierre) * 10000 + MONTH(p.fechaCierre) * 100 + DAY(p.fechaCierre) AS id_fechaFin,
    CAST(p.estado AS SIGNED INTEGER) AS estado_produccion,
    rendimiento_hectarea,
    rendimiento_bruto,
    superficie_producida,
    lluvia_produccion,
    gastos_produccion
FROM
    (SELECT 
        idlotes,
            idproduccion,
            idlotesproduccion,
            TRUNCATE(SUM(rb), 2) AS rendimiento_hectarea,
            TRUNCATE(SUM(rb * hp), 2) AS rendimiento_bruto,
            TRUNCATE(SUM(hp), 2) AS superficie_producida
    FROM
        lotesproduccion
    GROUP BY idlotesproduccion) AS lp
        JOIN
    ids_lotes il ON il.idLotesProduccion = lp.idlotesproduccion
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        c.idLote,
            SUM(c.lluvia) lluvia_produccion,
            lp.idlotesproduccion
    FROM
        clima c
    JOIN lotesproduccion lp ON c.idlote = lp.idlotes
    JOIN produccion p ON p.idproduccion = lp.idProduccion
    WHERE
        c.fecha >= p.fechaInicio
            AND c.fecha <= p.fechaCierre
    GROUP BY lp.idlotesproduccion) c ON c.idlotesproduccion = lp.idlotesproduccion
        JOIN
    produccion p ON p.idproduccion = lp.idProduccion
        JOIN
    ids_cultivos icu ON icu.idCultivos = p.idCultivo
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        lp.idlotesproduccion,
            hectareas,
            totalHp,
            CASE
                WHEN gp.costo IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE TRUNCATE((SUM(gp.costo) * (hectareas)) / (totalHp), 2)
            END AS gastos_produccion
    FROM
        gastosproduccion gp
    JOIN (SELECT 
        lp.idProduccion,
            lp.hp AS hectareas,
            lp1.totalHp AS totalHp,
            lp.idlotesproduccion
    FROM
        lotesproduccion lp
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        lp.idProduccion, SUM(lp.hp) AS totalHp
    FROM
        lotesproduccion lp
    GROUP BY lp.idProduccion) AS lp1 ON lp.idProduccion = lp1.idProduccion) AS lp ON lp.idProduccion = gp.idProduccion
    GROUP BY lp.idlotesproduccion) gp ON gp.idlotesproduccion = lp.idlotesproduccion
GROUP BY p.fechaInicio , p.fechaCierre , il.IdLoteNuevo , icu.idCultivosNuevo;
```

It's work great now, the only doubt is that when gp.costo is null, it should show 0 (because de case when) but instead is does not show the entirely row.

pd: I don´t know how to add code in a comment

Comment: At that time you need to do left join after gastosproduccion gp. Simply replace join with left join aftet gp table

Comment: Actually you are suppose to add that code in your question itself, at last with comments, dont add code like that in answer section.